# Delphi: idHTTP.Post erro HTTP/1.1 401

Tags: json, delphi

Estou tentando acesso pelo idHTTP do Delphi em um servidor json sem sucesso. Já tentei todas as alternativas e tenho sempre o mesmo erro: "HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized".

Formato Json enviado para testes:

> {"http":{"method":"POST","header":"access_token:55b3ce85b47629eeee778c0f0c9be450f1b1bc84cc377975f2d3d0d3808a4636",
>   "content":"name=TESTE&email=teste@uol.com.br&phone=1147001211&mobilePhone=11992329909&address=Rua+Jose+Ricardo
>   &addressNumber=55&province=Bairro&notificationDisabled=True&city=Sao+Paulo&state=SP&country=Brasil&postalCode=05567210
>   &cpfCnpj=11111111111&personType=FISICA"}}

Url para testes:

```
http://homolog.asaas.com/api/v2/customers
```

Procedure utilizada para testes:

```
procedure TForm4.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 sResponse: string;
 EnvStr : TStringList;
begin
 // 2
 EnvStr := TStringList.Create;
 EnvStr.AddStrings(Memo.Lines);
 try
  idHTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';
  idHTTP.Request.Method:='POST';
  idHTTP.Request.AcceptCharSet := 'utf-8';
  try
   sResponse := idHTTP.Post(EditURL.Text,EnvStr);
  except
   on E: Exception do
     ShowMessage('Error on request: '#13#10 + e.Message);
  end;
finally
 MemoRet.Lines.Clear;
 MemoRet.Lines.add(sResponse);
end;
```

end;

O mesmo formato enviado em PHP funciona perfeitamente, mas com idHTTP retorna o erro: "HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized".

Alguém já faz esse procedimento no Delphi com o asaas.com? Agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agradecimentos ao usuário Remy Lebeau (https://stackoverflow.com/users/65863/remy-lebeau), pela solução enviada em inglês!

```
procedure TForm4.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 sResponse: string;
 EnvStr : TStringList;
begin
 EnvStr := TStringList.Create;
 try
  EnvStr.Add('name=TEST');
  EnvStr.Add('email=teste@uol.com');
  EnvStr.Add('phone=1147001211');
  EnvStr.Add('mobilePhone=11992329909');
  EnvStr.Add('address=Rua Jose Ricardo ');
  EnvStr.Add('addressNumber=55');
  EnvStr.Add('province=Test');
  EnvStr.Add('notificationDisabled=True');
  EnvStr.Add('city=Sao Paulo');
  EnvStr.Add('state=SP');
  EnvStr.Add('country=Brasil');
  EnvStr.Add('postalCode=05567210 ');
  EnvStr.Add('cpfCnpj=11111111111');
  EnvStr.Add('personType=FISICA');

  Http.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['access_token'] := '55b3ce85b47629eeee778c0f0c9be450f1b1bc84cc377975f2d3d0d3808a4636';
  try
    sResponse := idHTTP.Post(EditURL.Text, EnvStr);
  except
    on E: Exception do
      ShowMessage('Error on request: '#13#10 + e.Message);
  end;
 finally
   EnvStr.Free;
   MemoRet.Text := sResponse;
 end; 
end;
```